# Windows 10 Powershell Clear Single DNS Entries

Tags: windows, powershell, dns

Using Windows 10 powershell (x64), Get-DnsClientCache, lists the DNS cache as such;

`Entry                          RecordName                Record Type    ....`
`------                         ----------                -----------    -----`
`ocsp.sectigo.com               ocsp.sectigo.com          AAAA`
`widgets.wp.com                 widgets.wp.com            A`
`ss64.com                       ss64.com                  A`
`ss64.com`
`github.githubassets.com        github.githubassets.com   A`
`github.githubassets.com`
`github.githubassets.com`

To flush the DNS cache, Clear-DnsClientCache, will clear just about the whole cache.

My question being, is it possible to clear only one record? For example, just flush out the, github.githubassets.com, record name, hence all entries to it, using powershell commands.

Thanks and regards,
njc

Comment: You can clear the cache, then use `Register-DnsClient` to refresh the `DnsClientCache`. I dont believe there is any way of removing one or more entries from cache via powershell atleast

Comment: Looking at the DNS_RECORD_FLAGS struct in Windns.h, it appears there is a Delete Member but it is apparently reserved for internal use or for dev at a later date as it's listed as 'Reserved.  Do not use.' -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/ns-windns-dns_record_flags?redirectedfrom=MSDN, so it appears it cannot be done.